# Why does my MySQL server keep converting HEAP to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, java, glassfish, hibernate

We ve been having some issues with our MySQL server intermittently. It keeps throwing out a lot of these queries concurrently (thus stacking them up in my processlist). We are using a MyISAM db and connection pooling through Glassfish v3 for a Grails Application.

db_user myhost:35143 db Query 39

```
converting HEAP to MyISAM /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.7 ( Revision: ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
```

We speculate that there are temp tables being created through GORM (the grails ORM) that are causing these queries.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a few things.

Most obvious would be your `TMP_TABLE_SIZE` variable is to small and MySQL must create the temporary table on disk and not in memory. Using the following query will show if MySQL is creating disk tmp tables.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE '%tmp%';
```

Other issue could be that the table that should go to a temp table is `BINARY` or `TEXT` table which the memory engine does not support and therefor you would get a MyISAM table created on disk.

Temporary tables created on disk are MyISAM tables. `HEAP` is the old name for `MEMORY` tables so you must be running on a pre MySQL 5.x version of MySQL.